# How many Integer values of $n$ are possible for $n^2+25n+19$ to be a perfect square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[1] How many Integer values of $n$ are possible for $n^2+25n+19$ to be a perfect square.

[2] How many Integer values of $n$ are possible for $n^2-19n+99$ to be a perfect square.

$\underline{\bf{My\;Try}}::$ for first one , Let $k^2 = n^2+25n+99$, where $k,n\in \mathbb{Z}$

So $4k^2 = 4n^2+100n+76\Rightarrow (2k)^2 = (2n)^2+2\cdot (2n)\cdot 25+625+(76-625)$

$(2k)^2 = (2n+25)^2-549\Rightarrow (2n+25)^2-(2k)^2 = 549 = 3^3\cdot 61$

Now Let $x= 2k$ and $y = (2n+25)$,

we get $(x^2-y^2)=(x+y)\cdot(x-y) = 3^2 \cdot 61$

Is it Right or not ,and is there is any other method to solve these type of questions,

If Yes the please explain here

Thanks

Comment: Oh Sorry I have edited it.Thanks Arthur.

Comment: You could also try to solve the quadratic equation n^2 + 25n + 19 - k^2 = 0, which will get you again around this magic 549 number ;)

Answer (score 6):

Let $$n^2+25n+19=(n+a)^2\text{ where }a\text{ is some integer }$$

$$\iff n=\frac{a^2-19}{25-2a}$$

Let integer $d$ divides both $a^2-19,25-2a$

$\implies d$ divides $\{2(a^2-19)+a(25-2a)\}=25a-38$

$\implies d$ divides $\{2(25a-38)+25(25-2a)\}=549=9\cdot61$

So, the divisors$(d)$ of $549$ are $\pm1,\pm3,\pm9\pm61,\pm183,\pm549$

As $25-2a$ must divide $a^2-19,$ check which values of $d(=25-2a)$ make $n$ integer

Comment: you forgot divisor 183 ;)

Comment: @Cristi, I generally write in pair like $\pm1,\pm649;\pm3,\pm183;\pm9,\pm61$ to avoid omission.Thanks anyway

Comment: Thanks lab bhattacharjee But I did not understand Let integer $d$ divides both $a^2-19,25-2a$

$\implies d$ divides $\{2(a^2-19)+a(25-2a)\}=25a-38$

Comment: @juantheron, if $d$ divides $a,b;d$ will divide $xa+yb$ where $x,y$ are integers, right?